# assembly reading binary number to decimal 8086 (NASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16

i dont see what am i doing wrong. I need to to binary calculator which input format is something like "00000001b+00000010b ... the output needs to be in binary too ... 
the operator can be +,-,*,/.

I want to read the first number and convert it to decimal ... my code is something like this

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

segment .text
    global _asm_main
_asm_main:
    enter 0,0
    pusha


    call read_int
    cmp al,'b'
    je vypis

vypis:
    call print_int


koniec:
    popa                 ; terminate program
    mov EAX, 0
    leave
    ret
```

the program works fine when the input start with number one for example (10101010b) but when the input start with zero it dont work properly ...

**my question what am i doing wrong or how can i do it better ?**

---

print_int and read_int are functions that are already given to us, they work on 100% ...
other functions that i can use are read_char, print_char and print_string ...

```
read_int:
    enter   4,0
    pusha
    pushf

    lea eax, [ebp-4]
    push    eax
    push    dword int_format
    call    _scanf
    pop ecx
    pop ecx

    popf
    popa
    mov eax, [ebp-4]
    leave
    ret

print_int:
    enter   0,0
    pusha
    pushf

    push    eax
    push    dword int_format
    call    _printf
    pop ecx
    pop ecx

    popf
    popa
    leave
    ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like `read_int` simply returns an integer value (in `eax`) that has been read by `scanf`. I'm not sure why you expect the least significant byte of that integer to be `'b'`(?).

Although I don't know which `scanf` implementation you're using, I haven't seen any that will directly read binary numbers. Implementing that functionality yourself is fairly easy though.
Here's some sample code in C showing the principle:

```
char bin[32];
unsigned int i, value;

scanf("%[01b]", bin);  // Stop reading if anything but these characters
                       // are entered.

value = 0;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(bin); i++) {
    if (bin[i] == 'b')
        break;
    value = (value << 1) + bin[i] - '0';
}
// This last check is optional depending on the behavior you want. It sets
// the value to zero if no ending 'b' was found in the input string.
if (i == strlen(bin)) {
    value = 0;
}
```